# How can I change the style attributes of an HTML tag?

Tags: jquery, html, tags

Consider the following tag:

```
<div class="my_class" style="width: 453px; height: 604px;">
    // stuff
</div>
```

I want to change it to:

```
<div class="my_class" style="height: 453px; width: 604px;">
    // stuff
</div>
```

I need to do this using jquery, and I won't necessarily know the values of `height` and `width`. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you trying to apply a style to all `div`s with a certain class?  Or to just that one `div` which also happens to have that class name?

Comment: All I want to do is change the `width` to the `height`, and the `height` to the `width`. Everything else stays the same.

Comment: It appears that sometimes the computer 'remembers' the old width and height settings. This is being used for an image rotation feature. Is there a way to 'flush the cache', or a way to prevent the computer from remembering the previous width and height settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will also handle the case where you want to do this to multiple elements at once:

```
$('.my_class').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var oldWidth  = $this.css('width'),
        oldHeight = $this.css('height');
    $this.css({
        width: oldHeight,
        height: oldWidth
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
var cls = $(".my_class"); 
var h = cls.height();
var w = cls.width();
cls.css({"width":h,"height":w})
```

Answer (score 2):

To swap width and height:

```
    $('.my_class').css({
        width: $(this).height(),
        height: $(this).width()
    });
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/qSHLV/)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the easiest/best way.

http://jsfiddle.net/rp9jx/1/

```
$('.my_class').removeAttr("style").attr({
  style: "height: 453px; width: 604px;"
});
```

Comment: The cleanest method, although I think prop (http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is the recommended jQuery method to use now in place of attr.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     $(function() {
     var Width  = $this.css('width'),
     height = $this.css('height');
     $(".my_class").width(width).height(height);
     });
```

or

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     var Width  = $this.css('width'),
     height = $this.css('height');
     $(".my_class").width(604).height(height);
     }) ;
```